# "Enthused" vs. "enthusiastic"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, past-participles

Is it grammatically correct to say "I was enthused" rather than "I was enthusiastic"?

If so, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: When I hear *enthused* I almost always want to hear it followed by "...about [*something*]." It seems to leave you hanging. I don't have the same reaction to "I was enthusiastic."

Answer (score 5):

The answer is one of preference, not grammar.

*Enthused* is a back-formation. Because it's newer, some people may be more used to hearing *enthusiastic*. Also, as the quote below indicates, the two words can have different implications.

Quoth the [grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/enthuse/):

> ... problems arise when enthused is used as a past-participle adjective in place of enthusiastic, which is a perfectly good, and far older, word. Plus, the adjective enthused can carry an ironic tone and is difficult to use in earnest.

Comment: But Enthused _can_ be a verb where as enthusiastic can't, so there are more significant differences surely? I enthused, he enthused etc... 

Also, what is back formation? Can you link me?

Comment: A participle can be part of a verb phrase. It is derived from a verb but not one itself. You may even say that both act as nouns in your sentences because of the copulative verb. Back-formation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation